# Rails find a line in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a big string where I have to find a specific line.

it looks like this:

```
[...]
Date: Fri, 22 May 2015 07:01:44 +0200
From: mail@somedomain.de
To: i@otherdomain.de
[...]
```

Now I want to know to which mail address it was sent. I want to read the line

```
To: i@otherdomain.de
```

As Result I need this:

```
i@otherdomain.de
```

What would be the easiest way to get this?

Comment: If you already know what it looks like, you don't even need to search, right? Please specify exactly what you are searching for (e.g. `Date:` with a specific date, or any line starting with `To:`, or consecutive `Date:`, `From:` and `To:` lines, ...?), and give a bit more of the string you are searching through - the non-matching areas are as important as matching ones.

Comment: Did you consider `grep`?

Comment: the mal adress changes every time. I need all behind the To:

Comment: You should remove the Rails tag. It may disappoint those only looking for Rails questions, and may be missed by those who filter on Ruby but filter out Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
big_string = <<EOF
...
Date: Fri, 22 May 2015 07:01:44 +0200
From: mail@somedomain.de
To: i@otherdomain.de
...
EOF

to_address = big_string[/^To: (.*)$/, 1]
# => i@otherdomain.de
```

Comment: thanks thats exactly what I want and need! so simple in rails can't believe it

Comment: Not Rails - pure Ruby.

Comment: oh okay :) I'm new in ruby and ruby on rails. Normaly I'm a java / php developer thanks a Lot

Comment: ...or `/^(?<=To:\s).*$/` or `/^To:\s+\K.*$/`. `(?<=To:\s )` is a positive lookbehind. `\K` means discard everything matched so far. Note lookarounds cannot have variable-length matches (such as `\s+`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice`,

```
input = "To: i@otherdomain.de"
input.slice!("To: ")
input #"i@otherdomain.de"
```